# php calling classes functions in separate pages

Tags: php, model-view-controller

I've worked with Java EE recently and like the idea of struts.xml where I can handle the redirection to pages based on return string from action classes.

In PHP, in my new under-development site, I am trying to follow the MVC standards without an MVC framework used from the internet. So I create the controllers, models and views (empty now). The only thing I am really stuck at is when I submit the form in view (insert_product.php) then I will need to create another php page to handle the post data and pass them to controllers.

Anyway of avoiding creating those pages and maybe having something like struts.xml? Even if I can post data directly to controller class, that would be good.

Comment: Since you have decided to go with MVC standards why done you use any PHP-MVC frameworks like Zend, CI, Symphony..

Comment: I used codeigniter and was able to bring up good functionality. But I just couldn't integrate shopping cart with it which is core requirement.

Comment: Building a shopping cart in Codeigniter should be a pretty simple exercise. Just saying...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The request cycle is:

```
            |
browser  ---|--->  Controller  ---+
         request                  |
   ^        |                     V
   |        |
   |        |                   Model
   |        |
   |        |                     |
   +--------|------  View  <------+
         response
            |
  client    |       server
```

As you see, the MVC separation is entirely a code organization strategy on the server side. You do not *need* separate files. Any GET or POST request is handled by a controller, the view is just returning a response (i.e. HTML). How the controller handles incoming requests and which controller handles which requests is entirely up to you, it has nothing to do with any particular files.

Answer (score 1):

> when I submit the form in view

This is a typical scenario that happens from a programmer first starting web-development comming from other development areas.

**You don't submit the form in the view.** The user requests a new page with *extra* information..

But mind you this, the user can't care less about your view. The user's browser will get some code that will then interpret and generate a page. The user page and your view (on an MVC in this scenario) are two complete different things!

The user makes a request to your server than may (or may not) contain extra information (POST / GET).

**That said, the controllers should get the information.** And then pass it on to the model if it's relevant.